# Filename overwrites the uploaded attachments

Tags: c#, asp.net

The file name is generated by Po+Invoice in the sql table. When user attach a pdf it overwrites the existing file name that has same po+invoice. Is there anyway i could create the unique id filename.

```
public partial class upload : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string mID;

    DataBaseDataContext dataBaseDataContext = new DataBaseDataContext();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }

    protected void SUbmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var ext = FileUploadtoServer.FileName.Substring(FileUploadtoServer.FileName.IndexOf('.') + 1, 3);
            if (ext.ToLower() != "pdf")
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Please select a pdf File!')</script>");
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Please select a pdf File!')</script>");
            return;
        }

        if (PO_Number.Text.Equals("") || HeadCode.Text.Equals("") || Manufacture.Text.Equals("") || Description.Text.Equals("") || Invoice.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Please Fill All Fields!')</script>");
        }

        TPT tPT = new TPT();
        tPT.Invoice_No = Invoice.Text;
        tPT.PO_Number = PO_Number.Text;
        tPT.Item_Code = Manufacture.Text;
        tPT.Heat_Code = HeadCode.Text;
        tPT.Description = Description.Text;
        tPT.FileName = PO_Number.Text + Invoice.Text + ".pdf";
        dataBaseDataContext.TPTs.InsertOnSubmit(TPT);
        dataBaseDataContext.SubmitChanges();

        String path = Server.MapPath("Attachments/" + PO_Number.Text + Invoice.Text + ".pdf");
        FileUploadtoServer.SaveAs(path);
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Successfully Inserted!')</script>");
        Invoice.Text = "";
        Manufacture.Text = "";
        HeadCode.Text = "";
        Description.Text = "";
        PO_Number.Text = "";
    }
}
```

I have tried

```
Guid.NewGuid() + ".pdf";,
```

it still does the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding -1,-2, i was able to upload it by adding date stamp

```
`tPT.FileName = PO_Number.Text + Invoice.Text + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".pdf";`
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would be to just take the file name, and add -1, then -2, then -3

So,

```
   mydoc.pdf
   mydoc-1.pdf
   mydoc-2.pdf
   etc. etc.
```

So, then say a function like this:

## Edit: Updated code

```
string GetServerFilenext(string strFileFullPath)
{
    string strFileToCheck = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            strFileToCheck = strFileFullPath;
        else
            strFileToCheck =
                Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileFullPath) + 
                @"\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strFileFullPath) +
                "-" + i.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(strFileFullPath);

        if (!File.Exists(strFileToCheck))
            break;
    }
    return strFileToCheck;
}
```

So, now your code becomes this:

```
 string sFileToSave = 
       Server.MapPath(@"~/Attachments/" + PO_Number.Text + Invoice.Text + ".pdf");

 sFileToSave = GetServerFileNext(sFileToSave);

 tPT.FileName = Path.GetFileName(sFiletoSave);
```

So, you setup the full path and file name.

You then check if it exists, and if not, then add -1, then -2 etc. etc.

## Edit2: So, code would look like this (warning: air code)

```
        string sFileToSave =
            Server.MapPath(@"~/Attachments/" + PO_Number.Text + Invoice.Text + ".pdf");

        sFileToSave = GetServerFileNext(sFileToSave);

        TPT tPT = new TPT();
        tPT.Invoice_No = Invoice.Text;
        tPT.PO_Number = PO_Number.Text;
        tPT.Item_Code = Manufacture.Text;
        tPT.Heat_Code = HeadCode.Text;
        tPT.Description = Description.Text;
        tPT.FileName = Path.GetFileName(sFileToSave);
        dataBaseDataContext.TPTs.InsertOnSubmit(TPT);
        dataBaseDataContext.SubmitChanges();

        FileUploadtoServer.SaveAs(sFileToSave);
```

Comment: Your code can/will/should be much the same as you have now. The only difference is you call that function with the full final desired file name you going to use at the START of your existing ocde. if file exists, it will add -1, then -2 to the end of the filename (if duplicate). It looks like you store only file name in database, so after we create/get/have a file name that does not exist, then when saving to the database we use Path.GetFilename which strips out the path part. Keep your code exactly as is, but create the full path + file name at start of your existing routine.

Comment: see my edit above - you only need that "check if file already exists, with that loop (for next) is called, and it keeps trying until it finds a un-used file name. That is the file name  of which your code that follows can then use.

Comment: Well, if the file does not already exists, then nothing is changed. it is only when you up-load a file again with the same name, then should the -1, -2 etc. gets added to the end of the file name. So, for most files - no change will occur. However, if the file already exists in the target folder, then a -1 will be appended to the file name. And the GetServerFilenext routine? Well, drop it into the current page code, but it is a rather handy routine, so it could/should/good idea to have that routine placed in your "general" library of code, but for now, just add that routine to the code behind.

Comment: i added it behind, sFileToSave = GetServerFileNext(sFileToSave);. Even if the file exist it didn't add -1,-2 because i need to add the function you have added. That is what i couldn't figure out.   Thanks for your help/suggestion

Comment: See my edit, there was a bug in that posted code. So, try the updated GetServerFileNext again. It should work now.